JavaScript Updated Why My Closure Not Giving Me Inner Closure Return Value
I'm trying to use closures but I can not get the value of the inner
closure I thought I understood closures when it came to strings working with values is different.  I get the output for result and final from the console but I only get the return value from result
what am I doing wrong. Can someone explain this to me or point me in the right direction. I would greatly appreciate I can't figure out what I am doing wrong
Code snippet:
 function solution(param1, param2) {

   var param1 = 1;
   var param2 = 2; 
   var result = param1 + param2;

 //anotherOne 
 /* wether I use this on or the call farther down 
    still get same results, I get two console out puts 
    3 and 1000 when I only want 1000 for the return 
    value*/

 function anotherOne(param1, param2){

   var param1 = 0;
   var param2 = 1000;

   var final = param1 + param2;
   console.log(result);
   console.log(final)
     return final
  }
     anotherOne()  
    return result;



}


 solution();


what do you expect to be the value of the inner closure - what do you the the inner closure is? you have a function within solution that is never called, why? What did you expect as the result of calling solution()

"I thought I understood closures when it came to strings." - closures have nothing to do with strings. They work the same with all types of values in the variables.

"I'm trying to use a closures but I can not get the value of the inner closure. What am I doing wrong?" - it's not really clear what you were trying to do. What result/output did you expect? What did you intend to do with the anotherOne function, which is not used anywhere in your code? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

I do get the value for result but not for another)ne which should be 1000,  I tried calling anotherOne as an object but it doesn't work example return{ anotherOne} but I get an error.

It works in individual functions

Its give me a return value of 3

Please [edit] your question to include the exact code where you tried to call anotherOne and the error your got. Maybe also include examples of where it works as you expect.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Looking over your code. I think this is what you were meaning to do? Correct me if I am wrong. In the inner function you're not returning that value? Which when returning you need to have one value or you can work in a solution to return both values. Is this what I'm understanding from your post?


function solution(param1, param2) {

   var param1 = 1;
   var param2 = 2; 
   var result = param1 + param2;

 //anotherOne 
 /* wether I use this on or the call farther down 
    still get same results, I get two console out puts 
    3 and 1000 when I only want 1000 for the return 
    value*/

 function anotherOne(param1, param2){

   var param1 = 0;
   var param2 = 1000;

   var final = param1 + param2;
   console.log(result);
   console.log(final)
     return final
  }
     anotherOne()  //You're not returning this value.
     return result; //Only returning the first value here.
}

solution();





function solution() {
    function anotherOne(param1, param2){
        var final = param1 + param2;
        return final;
    }
      
    return anotherOne(0, 1000);
}

console.log(solution());



